# Une autre définition et l'étymologie du nom « délivrance »

Tags: sens, étymologie

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deliverance affirme que:

> **deliverance** = 2. A formal or authoritative utterance

et que son étymologie provient de l'ancien français. Néanmoins, d'après Larousse, le nom [délivrance](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/d%C3%A9livrance/23132?q=delivrance#23014) ne semble pas posséder cette acception. 1. Est-ce vrai ? Pouvez-vous expliciter ?

2. Pouvez-vous éclaircir et énoncer comment le même nom peut entraîner deux définitions différentes ? L'étymologie, comment a-t-elle bifurqué ? Comment la rationaliser ?

Une remarque: Je bouquinais [After Stevens](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/03/22/after-stevens) lorsque j'ai croisé ce nom.

Comment: Pour avoir des réponses complètes académiques, le dictionnaire de référence en ligne : http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/d%C3%A9livrance

Comment: This question doesn't belong to French Language. In the *New Yorker* article you link to the word *deliverance* doesn't mean "A formal or authoritative utterance" but means "the act of setting free". And it is exactly the meaning the French word *délivrance* which has given both English words *delivery* (the act of giving birth - which is technically setting the baby from the mother's womb) and *deliverance* (the act of liberating). I think that what you want to know why the English word *deliverance* can at the same time mean an utterance and the act of liberating something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is not always obvious to give the most appropriate reason when voting to vote to close a question. Your question is more one of common sense than of English. When you make a speech, you liberate words, you deliver words, so you make a deliverance. There's really nothing far-fetched or mysterious about it.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about how an English word acquired its modern meaning, not about the meaning of etymology of a French word. It might be reformulated in a way that is on-topic for [english.se].

Comment: En français le mot n'a pas deux sens différents. C'est en anglais qu'il a apparemment deux sens différents (en fait c'est un seul et même sens, même en anglais, dans les deux cas il s'agit de « libération » / d'« expulsion »)

Comment: @Amphiteóth Je vous remercie de votre remarque. Voudriez-vous vous engager dans http://english.stackexchange.com/q/224823/50720, ou même améliorer cette question à moi?

Comment: @Amphiteóth Je vous en prie et merci encore. N'hésitez pas à poser votre question vous-même, et je serai heureux de la plussoyer !

Comment: Yw. _Délivrer_ is related to [libérer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/liberer) for meaning, but to [_livrer_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/livrer) in terms of construction; one meaning of _livrer_ (to surrender s.o to s.o else) is the opposite of _délivrer_ (to set free). In English it's one construct "to deliver", there is no form without the de-. Meanings relate to _set free_ and to _put in possession_, give. Those latter meanings are rendered with _livrer_ in Fr. or _délivrer_ if formalities were involved(but not fig. for a speech). [This](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/12995/3177). Ty