# Comment traduire « deliverances » (an utterance; esp. of a formal character) dans le contexte suivant ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, étymologie

La langue anglaise emploie le verbe [« *to deliver* »](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=deliver) dans le sens usuel de [*délivrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9livrer) en français (sens 1. similaire à libérer, *[t]irer de captivité*), mais aussi dans le sens de [*livrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/livrer) un bien (*[m]ettre en la possession de, à la disposition de*). Tel l'ancien emploi (sens 2.  *[d]onner, remettre, après avoir rempli certaines formalités.*), on en retrouve la trace dans le deuxième sens de [*délivrance*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9livrance), qui est aujourd'hui restreint essentiellement à des formalités (souvent administratives) ou à des domaines spécialisés, comme le droit (*le transport de la chose vendue*). Ceci dit, il n'est donc pas surprenant qu'en anglais on conçoive aisément  « délivrer un discours » (sic) dans le sens de le donner, de le prononcer, de le tenir…

---

C'est dans ce contexte que s'inscrit en anglais un sens archaïque ou peut-être même désuet de [*deliverance*](https://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n182/mode/1up) (7b) qui s'entend de « *an utterance; esp. of a formal character* », (une « délivrée » pourrait-on dire pour donner voix à l'origine du mot), et l'un des exemples présentés est le suivant:

> 1879 M. Arnold Fr. Critic on Milton[...] *Macaulay's writing...
>   often... is really obscure, if one takes his **deliverances**
>   seriously.*
>
> [ NED(OED1) ]

Comment doit-on traduire la citation, en particulier « *deliverances* », et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've seen it used to mean "oral presentations"/"discourses" especially by Belgian students, [*élocutions*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/francophonie/%C3%A9locution) (see for instance "[Les élocutions](http://www.ecoledebeez.be/index.php?page=elocutions)"):

> Exposé présenté en classe par un élève.

Therefore, the following would work:

> Ce que Macaulay écrit ... est souvent ... très obscur, [surtout] si
>   l'on prend au sérieux ses *élocutions*.

The reasoning for using this here is it leverages a specific use from the general rhetoric oriented [meanings](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9locution), which are based on the latin [root](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/gaffiot/583/%C3%A9locution) (see *elocutio*, *eloquium*) for *words* and *speech*, as one's "delivery" of a speech implies not only the giving of the speech, but also the "manner" in which one speaks as it is given. This may be contrasted with the more standard [*allocution*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/allocution), which is either characterized by brevity and authority or being occasion-specific. Unsurprisingly, the aforementioned words are related to [*locution*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/locution) and generally constitute variations thereof.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. See [*e-loquor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DE%3Aentry%20group%3D11%3Aentry%3Deloquor) vs. [*loquor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DL%3Aentry%20group%3D31%3Aentry%3Dloquor) and [*adlocutio*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/adlocutio).</sub>

Comment: Thanks! That Belgian usage was an eye-opener. It's very hard to discuss the _delivery/deliverance_ in a generic way without talking about the manner, the speech components, or the content itself. I think because the _delivery_ is actually based on the past participle _délivrée_, a word is required which contains both a "direction" and an object in French to render it, such as é/ad-locution. This is also how the "transport" is rendered. Otherwise the focus is on the context of the locution, its tone etc. Or using metaphores. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

L'« [**élucubration**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9lucubration)  » (de [*elucubro*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DE%3Aentry%20group%3D11%3Aentry%3Delucubro) -  « rédiger la nuit, avec grand soin ») semble appropriée, si possiblement ironique et parfois même péjorative(extraits):

> *Iron*., souvent *au plur*.
>
> **A.**- Action d'élucubrer; recherche laborieuse et patiente pour composer
>   un ouvrage érudit ou un texte d'une certaine longueur.
>
> **B.**− *P. méton*. Ouvrage, texte produit à force de veilles et de travail.
>   *Je prépare une petite élucubration pas trop sotte, émaillée de citations variées, pour montrer qu'on connaît un peu son Molière*; ... Colette, *Claudine à l'école*,1900, p. 201.
>
> *P. ext. et péj.* Production déraisonnable, extravagante. *Il y avait
>   dans sa bibliothèque un rayon réservé à la cabale, à la magie noire,
>   aux plus bizarres élucubrations* (A. Daudet, *Trente ans Paris*,1888, p.
>   71).
>
> [ Le Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé ]

On pourra aussi parler de l'« [*envolée lyrique*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/envol%C3%A9e/30167?q=envol%C3%A9e#30080) » (mais pas de l'« *envoyée* »), c'est-à-dire de l'*[é]lan oratoire ou poétique*, avec idée d'[*élévation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envol%C3%A9e). Les [*propos*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propos) ([*proponere*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/gaffiot/1259/proponere)) et les *[parole(s)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paroles)* ([*parabola*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DP%3Aentry%20group%3D10%3Aentry%3Dparabola)) s'avèrent sans doute les termes génériques les plus couramment utilisés pour rendre, de la manière la plus neutre qui soit, ce dont il est question ici.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Par ailleurs, des mots associés au contexte religieux peuvent aussi parfois être utiles, mais cela nécessite une connaissance plus approfondie du sujet auquel on réfère puisque leur utilisation fait davantage appel à une comparaison soit de la forme ou du ton du discours(je paraphrase les définitions au *TLFi*): [sermon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sermon) ([*sermo*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/gaffiot/1430/sermo)): *Discours religieux, genre littéraire, ou discours moralisateur*. - [oraison](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oraison) ([*oratus*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/oratus)): *Prière, invocation, discours(prononcé en public)*. - [exhortation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exhortation) ([*exhortatio*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/exhortatio)): *Discours poussant quelqu'un à faire qqc., prédication, figure de rhétorique*. - [admonestation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/admonestation) ([*admoneo*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/gaffiot/49/admoneo)): *Faire des remontrances.* - D'un autre ordre, la « [*digression*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/digression) » ([*disgradior*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/digressio)) quand le discours s'écarte du sujet, mais ceci constitue donc aussi une forme de qualification des propos tenus.</sub>